# MongoDb find all objects that contain nested value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, axios

This is my user object sent as token in req:

```
{
    "_id": "6212aba16653621e67393549c",
    "name": "User",
    "email": "user@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0
}
```

This is my get function code:

```
const getSharedLists = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const lists = await List.find({
    sharedWith: { email: req.user.email },
  });

  res.status(200).json(lists);
});
```

This is what object looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "621817233300dfff68e23710",
    "user": "6212ab33383621e67393549c",
    "listName": "test update",
    "private": true,
    "items": [
        {
            "itemName": "Bananas",
            "quantity": 3,
            "isBought": false,
            "isle": "isle",
            "_id": "621b043622147906eece2e72"
        },
    ],
    "sharedWith": [
        {
            "email": "user@gmail.com",
            "_id": "621bdbf0791a322534284c49"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2022-02-24T23:39:25.668Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-02-27T21:21:03.584Z",
    "__v": 0,
},
```

I keep getting empty array back, even when hard code req.user.email as "user@gmail.com" for example. I need to find all lists on MongoDb that have my email in array of sharedWith.

Can somebody help please. Apparently I'm using List.find method wrong but can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need (`.`) dot notation.

```
const lists = await List.find({
  "sharedWith.email" : req.user.email
});
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KaBqy-Z1ab4)

---

**Reference**

[Specify a Query Condition on a Field Embedded in an Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-embedded-in-an-array-of-documents)